# Update table with matching primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `TABLE1` and `TABLE2`.

I need to update `TABLE1` with the matching primary keys from `TABLE2`.

Here is my code to get the primary key from TABLE1:

```
SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T  
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE C ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = T.CONSTRAINT_NAME  
WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1'  
  AND T.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

This is the code to get primary key for TABLE2:

```
SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T  
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE C ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = T.CONSTRAINT_NAME  
WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE2'  
  AND T.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

And this code is used to update TABLE1:

```
MERGE INTO <TABLE1> 
USING <TABLE2> ON (TABLE1.COLUMN_NAME = TABLE2.COLUMN_NAME)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET <TABLE1.COLUMN_NAME> = <TABLE1.COLUMN_NAME>
```

I need to merge all snippets of code to update the TABLE1, please help me how to get the primary keys and update with a single code.

Comment: Maybe dynamic sql could help you. Is there a reason you cannot just type the primary key names and you have to get them like that ?

Comment: as i have 2000 tables so i just want  to do it programmatically but not to hardcode

Comment: Then dynamic sql will be what you need. When you search for that you will find plenty of examples on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

As @GuidoG recommended, you will probably need to use dynamic SQL to perform this feat. Furthermore, from your question it is hard to figure out how to determine that Table1 and Table2 are related to one another.

Let us suppose that you have a table with table pairs available, and Table1 and Table 2 are one of those pairs. We'll need to figure out what the primary keys of both tables are, and then build the dynamic SQL using this information.

```
DECLARE @tableCombinations TABLE ([MainTable] NVARCHAR(255), [SubTable] NVARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @tableCombinations ([MainTable], [SubTable]) VALUES ('Table1','Table2')

DECLARE @q NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

;WITH PrimaryKeys AS (
    SELECT [Schema_Name] = sch.[name]
        , [Table_Name] = tbl.[name]
        , [Column_Name] = cols.[name]
    FROM [sys].[indexes] i
    JOIN [sys].[index_columns] ic ON i.[index_id] = ic.[index_id] AND i.[object_id] = ic.[object_id]
    JOIN [sys].[columns] cols ON cols.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND cols.[column_id] = ic.[column_id]
    JOIN [sys].[tables] tbl ON ic.[object_id] = tbl.[object_id]
    JOIN [sys].[schemas] sch ON tbl.[schema_Id] = sch.[schema_id] 
    WHERE i.[is_primary_key] = 1
)
SELECT @q += 'MERGE INTO ' + QUOTENAME(pkMain.[Schema_Name]) + '.' + QUOTENAME(pkMain.[Table_Name]) +' mt
              USING ' + QUOTENAME(pkSub.[Schema_Name]) + '.' + QUOTENAME(pkSub.[Table_Name]) + 'st ON (
                  mt.' + QUOTENAME(pkMain.[Column_Name]) + ' = st.' + pkSub.[Column_Name] + ')
              WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET mt.' + QUOTENAME(pkMain.[Column_Name]) + ' = st.' + pkSub.[Column_Name] + ';' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM @tableCombinations tc
JOIN [PrimaryKeys] pkMain ON tc.[MainTable] = pkMain.[Table_Name]
JOIN [PrimaryKeys] pkSub ON tc.[SubTable] = pkSub.[Table_Name]

SET @q = REPLACE(@q, '              ', '')
SELECT @q
```

Of course, if this yields the correct results, you can directly execute this query using [sys].[sp_executesql]. For more reliable results, be sure to include the schema names of the table combinations.

Comment: i just replaced the Table1 and Table2 as per my tablenames with your code and the updatation is not done... am i going wrong ?? and im not good at dynamic sql programming

Comment: Have you executed the resulting @q statement? Another thing I was wondering: what is your goal here? Do you want to merge two tables or to update something? I am asking this, because what you are currently doing when a match occurs is updating the key value on which it is already matching.

Comment: yes, i executed @q statement . what i need to do is... i have two tables, Table1 eg....    
col1 col2 col3
1 XX XXX
2 YY YYY
3 ZZ ZZZ
and Table2 eg..                                                                                                            col1 col2 col3
1 AA AAA
2 YY YYY
3 ZZ ZZZ
4 BB BBB                                                                                                                       ,here i need to update the Table1 with the Table2